# How do I remove the parent node without removing its child nodes as well?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML structure:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <item1>item 1</item1>
        <item2>item 2</item2>
        <item3>item 3</item3>
        <item4>item 4</item4>
        <generated-items>
            <item5>item 5</item5>
            <item6>item 6</item6>
        </generated-items>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item1>item 1</item1>
        <item2>item 2</item2>
        <item3>item 3</item3>
        <item4>item 4</item4>
        <generated-items>
            <item5>item 5</item5>
            <item6>item 6</item6>
        </generated-items>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item1>item 1</item1>
        <item2>item 2</item2>
        <item3>item 3</item3>
        <item4>item 4</item4>
        <generated-items>
            <item5>item 5</item5>
            <item6>item 6</item6>
        </generated-items>
    </list>
</root>
```

What I want to do is remove the parent tag of the repeating part of the XML file, which should result in the following outcome:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <item1>item 1</item1>
        <item2>item 2</item2>
        <item3>item 3</item3>
        <item4>item 4</item4>
        <item5>item 5</item5>
        <item6>item 6</item6>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item1>item 1</item1>
        <item2>item 2</item2>
        <item3>item 3</item3>
        <item4>item 4</item4>
        <item5>item 5</item5>
        <item6>item 6</item6>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item1>item 1</item1>
        <item2>item 2</item2>
        <item3>item 3</item3>
        <item4>item 4</item4>
        <item5>item 5</item5>
        <item6>item 6</item6>
    </list>
</root>
```

What is the best way to do this? I tried to copy the child nodes and paste them inside the repeating list element to make them part of that section, then removing the generating-items element all together.. Although I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way of doing this, and it gets messy real fast this way.

Comment: Can you share your code with us?  It makes it easier to offer a solution when we know how you're reading/processing the XML already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use XSLT-1.0 to transform your input XML to your desired output XML.
This can be achieved by using [`XslCompiledTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=netframework-4.8).
The following stylesheet (`transform.xslt`) does the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Identity template --> 
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="generated-items">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The necessary C# code is identical to the example in the link:

```
// Load the style sheet.
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("transform.xslt");

// Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
xslt.Transform("input.xml", "output.xml");
```

Then `output.xml` contains the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> generated_items = doc.Descendants("generated-items").ToList();

            foreach (XElement generated_item in generated_items)
            {
                generated_item.AddAfterSelf(generated_item.Descendants());
                generated_item.Remove();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using linq2xml, you can do this:

```
var xml = /* xml */;
var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
foreach(var generated in root.XPathSelectElements(@"list/generated-items").ToArray())
{
    generated.AddAfterSelf(generated.Descendants());
    generated.Remove();
}
```